# Using a list to populate model form foreign key in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to restrict my modelform foreign key instances using a list:

here is my model:

```
class Voicemail(models.Model):
    internalline = models.ForeignKey(InternalLine)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Then in init method of a corresponding model form I have

```
class VoicemailForm(ModelForm):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  ....
  ....
 # self.fields['internalline'].queryset = self.person.getPersonLines()  # this throws error in template.
   self.fields['internalline'].queryset = self.person.line.all()

   print(self.person.getPersonLines())
   print(self.person.line.all())
```

The two prints print identical output:

```
[<InternalLine: 1111>, <InternalLine: 5555>]
[<InternalLine: 1111>, <InternalLine: 5555>]
```

In getPersonLines, I do some additional logic and return a list of lines:

```
def getPersonLines(self):
    lines = []
    for line in self.line.order_by('extension'):
        lines.append(line)
    for phone in self.phonesst_set.all():
        for line in phone.line.order_by('extension'):
            if line not in lines:               
                lines.append(line)   

    return lines
```

Now when I try to render in template, if I use the list returned by getPersonLines, I get and error,

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'
```

But the same thing works if I populate the queryset using self.person.line.all()..

Am I missing something while trying to populate my queryset using a list?

Thanks in advance!!

**Update**

Here is the stack trace with

```
self.fields['internalline'].choices = self.person.getPersonLines()  

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 27, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 95, in __unicode__
    return self.as_table()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 217, in as_table
    errors_on_separate_row = False)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in _html_output
   'field': unicode(bf),
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 408, in __unicode__
   return self.as_widget()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 439, in as_widget
   return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 516, in render
   options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 533, in render_options
for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
TypeError: 'InternalLine' object is not iterable
```

**Update 2:**

This is the entire `__init__` method

```
class VoicemailForm(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   try: 
        self.person = kwargs.pop('person', None)
        super(VoicemailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'required_field'

        print(self.person.getPersonLines())
        print(self.person.line.all())
        if self.person:
            self.fields['internalline'].choices = self.person.getPersonLines()  
            #self.fields['internalline'].queryset = self.person.line.all()

   except Exception as e:
       print("Error overwriting __init__ of VoicemailForm")
       print(e)
```

This is how I call my form

```
voicemail = VoicemailForm(person=person, prefix='voicemail')
```

**Update 3**
I tried to create a django form as follows:

```
class test(forms.Form):
 line = forms.ChoiceField()
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['line'].choices=person.getPersonLines()
```

But I continue to get the same error
`for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
TypeError: 'InternalLineSST' object is not iterable`

Then I tired something like:

```
test = [1,2,3]
class myform(forms.Form):
    line = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['line'].choices = test

>>> form = myform()
>>>print(form)
```

which gives me a similar error

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 439, in as_widget
 return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 516, in render
 options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 533,in render_options
for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My purpose was using the list was I wanted to merge two query sets to display options for a  foreign key.

Based on

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/0i6KjzeM8OI

I modified my method to return a queryset instead of a list:

```
def getPersonLines(self):
    vm_lines = self.line.all()
    for phone in self.phonesst_set.all():
        vm_lines = vm_lines | phone.line.all()
```

and in the `__inti__` method of the form, I could use the query set

```
self.fields['internalline'].queryset = self.person.getPersonLines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the `.all()` and the `.order_by()` methods are part of the Django Queryset. They are not the same as a Python list. Although the representation is the same, they are indeed different.

Some code in the Django ModelChoiceField does expect a foreignkey to have a queryset instead of a list of results. If you set `self.fields['internalline'].choices` instead, you won't have this problem.

So try this instead:

```
self.fields['internalline'].choices = self.person.getPersonLines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, when I try that I get an error

Caught TypeError while rendering: 'InternalLine' object is not iterable

This is how I render in template
{{ voicemail }}

Comment: @akotian: could you provide the stacktrace for that error? I'm wondering what is happening there.

Comment: This makes no sense... setting the `.choices` property calls the `_set_choices()` method on the `ChoiceField`. And that method forces the input to be a list, hence, iterable. Can you show the entire `__init__` method of your form? It has to initialize the parent before accessing the `self.field`

Comment: I have added the `__init__` method, as an update. Thanks again!!

Comment: @akotian: looking at the code this shouldn't be possible, but... we can try further :) What if you give the form a `internalline = forms.ChoiceField()` attribute? That way we're at least sure that it's not a weird modelform thing.

Comment: Thanks for pursuing this in such detail!! Really appreciate it!! I have added an update 3 if you would please take a look!
Thanks!!

Comment: I was able to modify the method getPersonLines based on [link]https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/0i6KjzeM8OI[link] to use something like
`def getPersonLines(self):`
        `vm_lines = self.line.all()`
        `for phone in self.phonesst_set.all():`
            `vm_lines = vm_lines | phone.line.all()` This returned a queryset, which rendered without trouble.
Thanks for looking into this though!!